# How to show uniqueness of representation of an element in $\mathbb C^\ast$

Tags: group-theory

Let $\mathbb C^\ast = \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ and $\mathbb R^+ = \mathbb R_{>0}$ and $T=S^1$. I want to show that $x \in \mathbb C^\ast$ can be represented uniquely as $rz$ where $r \in \mathbb R^+ $ and $z \in T$.

What I have so far:

Let $a+ ib \in \mathbb C^\ast$. Then $r = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}\in  \mathbb R^+$ and ${a + ib \over r}\in T$.

Now I need to show uniqueness but I'm stuck:

Let $rz$ and $r'z'$ be such that $rz = r'z'$.

> How can I show that $r=r'$ and $z=z'$?

Note that I can finish the proof using the map $\varphi : \mathbb C^\ast \to \mathbb R^+ \times T, a + bi \mapsto (\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}, {a+bi \over \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}})$ by showing this map is both injective and surjective.

So proving the claim is not my problem.

My problem is that I can't seem to show uniqueness in the proof where I don't have $\varphi$. (In fact, I think it is a proof where I implicitly use $\varphi^{-1}$).

Anyway, I want to be able to prove it in both ways. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
&          & rz &= r'z' \\
& \implies & |rz| &= |r'z'| \\
& \implies & |r|\,|z| &= |r'|\,|z'| \\
& \implies & |r| \cdot 1 &= |r'| \cdot 1 \\
& \implies & r = |r| &= |r'| = r'. \\
\end{align}$$

Then $rz = r'z' \implies z = \frac{r'}{r}z' = z' $.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

$$rz = r'z' \Longrightarrow \frac{r}{r'} = \frac{z'}{z}.$$

The left hand side is a positive number, the right hand side is a unimodular number. What does this say about $\frac{r}{r'}$ and hence what can you conclude about $\frac{z'}{z}$?